# Adodb doesn't support security practices?

Tags: php, mysql, adodb

I started using ADODB for php5 as i wanted to *upgrade* my tools from the regular mysql functions but i'm surprised that it's not cleaning up queries from sql injections at all, is this actually supported and how to enable it?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: ADODB won't do your job for you. It can ease it, but it's not a magic wand which can be used without any understanding.

Comment: @Col. Shraphel i suggest you to work on your tune. i know that most programmers are like that, but it won't hurt to be more "socially" friendly.

Comment: It's not a tone, but note. A very simple one: as a matter of fact, Mysql functions are no less secure than ADODOB, when used properly. And ADODB won't help if used mindlessly. So, you need not some "magic" tool but understanding. Clear enough?

Comment: Also, you have to work on your attitude. It's not "ADODB doesn't support security practices". It' you aren't using it. Feel the difference.

Comment: i'm not really that dumb, i understood & i just gave you another "note". although it isn't really impossible to implement a tiny feature to clean up rows in ADODB, is it? so that feature is what i asked for..

Comment: I appreciate it, but i'm an adult and i know how social people sound.

Comment: Nope. It's impossible. And, to let you know, there is no need to clean anything. Just syntax rules which you'd better start to learn already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A prepared statement protects you from SQL injection, from the ADODB docs:

```
$arr = array(

         array('Ahmad',32),
         array('Zulkifli', 24),
         array('Rosnah', 21)

         );

$ok = $db->Execute('insert into table (name,age) values (?,?)',$arr);
```

However, having used both ADODB and PDO, I'd highly recommend you look into learning PDO instead.

Comment: thank you so much for the help, but i don't really know how that would work with SELECT & WHERE. any ideas?

Comment: The same way -- any placeholder in your SQL (a ?) is replaced by the values of the array in order, ie. `$db->Execute("SELECT field FROM TABLE WHERE COND=?", array($val));` You can [find the manual here](http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm). And again, if you're just learning now, I strongly advise you choose PDO over ADODB as you'll have a larger group of people you can get help from, and be using a more robust, vetted library.

Comment: Thanks, i think i'm going to switch to PDO!

Comment: Just go with PDO.. it's built into core.